# Cannot open Software Center

Tags: 14.04, updates, software-center, update-manager, 15.10

When I try to open the software center I see this error

**New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?**

[image]

The strange thing is if I tap on repair I see this:

[image]

I don't know If it can be an help but yesterday i tried to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10 without success. And I have this problem from yeserday.

Can someone help me?

after **sudo apt-get install -f**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-horai-umefont fonts-wqy-microhei gnome-exe-thumbnailer icoutils
  libcapi20-3 libmpg123-0 libopenal-data libopenal1 linux-headers-3.19.0-25
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic linux-signed-image-3.19.0-25-generic
  ttf-wqy-microhei wine-gecko2.21 wine-mono0.0.8 winetricks
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bluez-cups cups cups-core-drivers cups-daemon hplip indicator-printers
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcupsmime1
  printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp
  printer-driver-splix skype ubuntu-minimal ureadahead wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  libc-bin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 20 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
22 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 173 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?] Yes, do as I say!
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

after

**sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups-daemon : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.14 is to be installed
               Depends: lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu7) but 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6 is to be installed
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.21-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.21-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) but 2.21-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) but 2.21-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libcupsmime1 : Depends: libcups2 (= 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.6) but 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
 skype : Depends: skype-bin but it is not installable
 ureadahead : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.14 is to be installed
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install -f`. Add the output to your question.

Comment: The post was just edited!!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin`

Comment: E: Unable to locate package –

Comment: `sudo apt-add-repository main; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin`

Comment: edited, but unfortunately gives me another error

Comment: I know. But we have a chance. Give me the output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a` after that run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and add the output here http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13506980/

Comment: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and add the output here http://paste.ubuntu.com and give me the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32147/discussion-between-a-b-and-giovanni-giampaolo).